# Derived method is not called in CLI/C++

Tags: visual-studio-2012, dll, c++-cli, clr

I'm programming in CLI/C++, using Visual Studio 2012.

(As one sentence summary, my problem is the derived method's are not called(but base method's are called) when base classes are assembled into a DLL and used & overriden in another project.)

I have Card and CardManager classes(Base classes) and ComplexCard class in my project.  Previously, I had these base classes and complex classes in the same project but now I'm trying to seperate base classes as a new project(Project A), which will be compiled as .net dll.

In Card class I have a

```
virtual void HandleMessage(NativeStruct *, INT32U *);
```

method. This CardManager and Card classes are in Project A, which is build as .net DLL.

In project B, I referenced A.DLL and derived a class named ComplexCard from Card class. (I can debug by step in ComplexCard constructor and verify that  Base class's Constructor is also called. So I think I succesfully derived from Card class). I added this class to a list in CardManager.

When a message is received, card->HandleMessage() method is called in CardManager class. Since CardManager is in project A, card is Card type. But since it is created and added as ComplexCard, they are in fact ComplexCards. So when card->HandleMessage() method is called,  I suppose ComplexCard's HandleMessage method will be called, but base class's HandleMessage method is called each time and Complex Class's is never called(Polymorphism). Also, When I debug, I can veriyf that card is ComplexCard type in Watch fields.

I tested these codes in the project when Base and Complex classes are in same project and ComplexCard->HandleMessage() is called each time when I call it.

So, I think this problem happened when I transfer base classes into another DLL project and referenced them in the other project. What should I do to see the expected behaviour, to see ComplexCard->HandleMessage () is called.

Card.h

```
virtual void HandleMessage(S_MESSAGE *message);
```

ComplexCard.h

```
virtual void HandleMessage(S_MESSAGE *message) override;
```

CardManager.cpp > Message Receiver Method

```
S_MESSAGE message;
// message is filled
Card ^card = this->GetCard(remote_ip); // Get the card from list
card->HandleMessage(message); // Call the handlemessage method. PROBLEM is here
```

CardManager.cpp > GetCard method:

```
Card ^CardManager::GetCard(String ^value){

// These cards in Cards list are all ComplexClass type, not Base Card type
   for each(Card ^card in Cards){
      if(value == card->value){
         return card;
      }
   }
   return nullptr;
}
```

---

I have a base CardFactory and ComplexCardFactory. When I create CardManager, I set the ComplexCardFactory instance with a  setter method. So when CardManager requires a card, it uses ComplexCardFactory.

When a message is received, CardManager handles the messsage and gets a/the card from CardFactory. When I step into  method code here, I see thaty ComplexCardFactory is producing a ComplexCard and returns it. The returned  Card instance is added to Cards list.

After this step, card->HandleMessage is called but Card->HandleMessage is called, not ComplexCard->HandleMessage.

The simplified code that adds new card is:

```
Card ^ComplexCardFactory::GetCard(String ^value)
{
  ComplexCard ^new_card = gcnew ComplexCard(value);
  return new_card;

}

//and then. Verified that ComplexCardFactory is producing the card and its type is ComplexCard.
Cards->Add(new_card);
```

Comment: Obviously something is wrong in your code but no one can tell what exactly unless you show us the code (at least simplified version).

Comment: I've tested it and it seems to work fine (even when I splitted base and derived classes into 2 separate dll(s)). How do you add items to a `Cards` collection?

Comment: Ok, everything seems to be fine. Another guess: maybe the `HandleMessage` methods have different signatures? Is it possible that you have two different definitions for `S_MESSAGE` struct? How it is defined?

Comment: I manually call ComplexCard->HandleMessage and inside it, call __super::HandleMessage and it works. Also when I remove override word, code is not compiled and gives error(this decleration matches functiın in .dll hence override or new is required)

Comment: Can you try to declare `virtual void HandleMessage()` method in `Card` class without parameters(!) and the overriden one `virtual void HandleMessage() override` in a `ComplexCard`, call that methods from `CardManager` and see if the issue still exists.

Comment: A success! ComplexCard 's HandleMessage is called! So that means signatures does not match?

Comment: Normally my handlemessage takes 2 params. 1st is S_MESSAGE *(native struct),2nd is int *. I tried for one parameter versions, int * worked but S_MESSAGE * doesnt. So I think problem is about S_MESSAGE native struct. The only thing i did about this struct is to use the function, make it public with #pragma make_public(S_MESSAGE) (otherwise i cannot use the managed HandleMessage(S_MESSAGE*) method

Comment: Yepp! For some reason `HandleMessage` in a `ComplexCard` calss is not resolved as an overriden version of a base class method. I bet that something is wrong with the parameters.

Comment: I guess I found a way to reproduce it. Try adding `#pragma make_public(S_MESSAGE)` to a `Card.h`.

Comment: So it doesn't work with `make_public`?

Comment: Nope, i cant make it work.

Comment: That's strange... Where's the `S_MESSAGE` struct declared?

Comment: In header file, which only contains the struct definition and some enums. And then in the same header, there are #pragma make_public s. In my project, I #include this header file in Card.h file in order to see S_MESSAGE struct.

Comment: In object browser, when I expand BaseClass project,  there are __unnamed structs. I think they are my native structs. But when I expand BaseClass .dll, these structs have names(S_MESSAGE) and  it is "public:value class S_MESSAGE". So they are becoming value classes?

Comment: You also include that header in `ComplexCard.h`, right?

Comment: Yes, otherwise I get syntax error: identifier S_MESSAGE. Since it is native struct, I think I should include the header file like that. Right?

Comment: Yes, sure. That's silly question, I know :) I just out of ideas what may cause it.

Comment: I asked because Im not sure of it anymore, not to criticize your question :)